# "~that is being taught with kids that babies are racist?"

Tags: prepositions

This is from [a news podcast](https://www.npr.org/2022/03/23/1088169655/morning-news-brief).

> MARTINEZ: And Senator Ted Cruz from Texas focused on Jackson's role on
> the board of Georgetown Day School. That's a private school in D.C.
> Cruz focused on the school's curriculum that includes a book on how to
> talk to children about racism by Professor Ibram Kendi.
>
> TED CRUZ: Do you agree with this book that is being taught **with** kids
> that babies are racist?

and this is from [*The Washington Post* article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/books/2022/03/23/ted-cruz-ketanji-brown-jackson-books/).

> Noting that “Antiracist Baby” is being taught to children ages 4
> through 7, Cruz asked Jackson, “Do you agree with this book that is
> being taught **to** kids that babies are racist?”

I wonder which preposition is more appropriate in the above context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To" sounds grammatical to me.

"With" sounds pretty borderline, maybe ungrammatical.

It would make more sense in a sentence like "These are activities being run with kids" or "These songs are being sung with kids" - something where the verb indicates the children are participating actively.

I'd also note that even with **to** I think the sentence needs a comma:

> Do you agree with this book that is being taught to kids, that babies are racist?

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Agreed with Steve Bennett's answer. As an additional note, the difference between the two sources may stem from the first being a direct audio transcription, while the second is part of an article. While many news outlets have a stated policy that they don't "clean up" quotations, often some things do get tweaked. Here's an article about that: https://slate.com/news-and-politics/2010/03/do-newspapers-ever-correct-a-speaker-s-broken-english.html